# Как подключать к NPM библиотеки JS и CSS?

Tags: npm

Я захотел изучать TypeScript и столкнулся с npm. TS я установил глобально и все работает. Но возник вопрос, как подключать библиотеки JS (Jquery, vue.js и другие), CSS (normalize.css и др.)? Я установил например normalize (npm i normalize.css - как было написано на оф. сайте), как теперь его подключить к сайту? Не писать же в link href="node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css"? JS файлы (тот же gulp я ставил) подключаются просто require(...), а вот с css у меня ступор. Объясните, как с ним работать?

Comment: Думаю, будет полезно - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRo2tvQpus8&ab_channel=TraversyMedia

Comment: @Voprositel Ну это импорт/экспорт когда файл рядом. А если он в папке node_modules? Вот что меня интересует. Как прописывать путь или как подключать? Не писать же полностью `import * as $ from "node_modules/jquery/jquery.js"`?

Comment: Просто пишите `import * as $ from 'jquery'`. В данном случае импорты автоматически поймут, что импортируется из node_modules

Comment: @Voprositel а как быть с CSS?

Comment: https://overcoder.net/q/38715/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-materialize-css-%D1%81-react

Comment: @Voprositel т.е. нужно использовать Webpack для импорта, или же без npm как обычно?